# Django url prefix association

Tags: django

I'm very new to Django & hoping I can get some guidance on a question I had. I want to have multiple URL prefixes each with a different site prefix for my client's projects for example `client1.website.com`. Each prefixed site will have a different database associated. Is this something that's possible to do with Django? Can some please point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

While this is possible to do in django its towards the advanced usecase. Your best bet will be to look at the [sites framework](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/contrib/sites/) which will get you somewhere to where you want to be.
The issue (well complication) will be the multiple databases. Django is really geared up to using one set of databases per all sites.

If multiple databases is required then you could look at using one code base with multiple entry points (multiple settings files) one per website. You will then effectively be running one instance of django per host.

You mentioned you are new to django. I don't want to seem negative but... I would highly recommend you start with the django tutorial, learn the basics and work up from there. Jumping straight in thinking you can building a reasonably complicated multi host website with multiple databases is not going to be realistic. Even devs with multiple years in django would find this a large undertaking.